# How to programmatically trigger a draggable "move" event by a click in Vue?

Tags: vue.js, draggable, vuedraggable

I have a set of cards that are arranged vertically and are currently draggable. When you drag a card over another, you see this card as a semi-transparent card hovering over the target position, before you let go, the cards underneath swap positions.

I want to know how to trigger that behavior(swap positions/show animation of moving up/down) without dragging eg. click arrows up/down.

**To clarify**: "trigger event" as in not call the method that responds to the moving event(ending) but make the cards move as if a mouse/finger dragged the cards in a direction(up/down).

For now I have added a position switch that reorders the array but it does not trigger the visual aspect eg. dragging. You just see a flash and then cards are ordered differently.

See visual behavior

[before move](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r8tSG.png)

[during move](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mytBo.png)

[after move](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7m1rn.png)

Draggable component

```
<draggable v-model="things" :move="checkPosition" :options={animation:500}">
  <div v-for="(thing, index) in things">
    <div class="up" @clickSort"('up', index)">
    <div class="down" @clickSort"('up', index)">
  </div>
</draggable>
```

Relevant JS methods

```
watch: {
  things: {
    // this fires when you sort by dragging, as well as button click
    // loop over things
    // update vuex
  }
}

checkPosition(event) {
  if (event.related) {
    // code that keeps draggable item pos in scope of existing elements
    // some are hidden
    return !event.related.classList.contains('locked');
  }
}

clickDrag(direction, itemPos) {
  // manual array sorting, no draggable event eg. hover/motion/transition
}
```

Comment: Create a [MouseEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent) and [dispatch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/dispatchEvent) it in the window or whatever.

Comment: What does that mean? If it wasn't clear, I can trigger the events related to the dragging motion(in progress/done) I currently can't make the cards move as if they were being dragged by clicking the arrows. I've considered adding something that literally moves the cards like translate or something I don't know if it would trigger the draggable hooks. To move the cards currently you have to click/hold/drag whether by mouse or touch.

Comment: To "make the cards move as if a mouse/finger dragged the cards in a direction", you need to create events, like the mouse does in those situations. You'll create mousedown, mousemove, and mouseup events, and dispatch them on the draggable.

Comment: Oh dang, okay I will have to look into that, I wonder if you specify like "pixels" but what about speed, etc... will keep in mind

Comment: @it_is_written please post your solution. i am also having the same problem Thanks

Comment: What was the contents of `clickDrag`? I'm trying to achieve something similar.

Answer (score 0):

In  order to create this transition effect, you must use Enter/Leave Transition provided by Vue https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html

You will need to define css animation styles that Vue will apply to your components when you want to trigger the animation, like ondrop event.

Comment: Yeah I think I just decided to "fake it"(mostly due to time constraint) by adding temporary classes to slide up/fade a little but in the end it's not the same as an actual "draggable event" but I can trigger the events that occur when you let go. I don't know if it's possible/makes sense what I was trying to do. I also can't tell right away if the drag release event re-renders the component like when I update the card order state.

Comment: Going this route though it looks rough, probably should try to prevent render or better just go with mouse events as suggested above. At least when the class is removed, and it "snaps back to place" after having been re-rendered. At least with how I implemented it(using css transitions and adding/removing classes.

Comment: Actually it worked out, I needed to not have the transition delay apply when you remove the class